# Column sum is NaN in Javascript (ExtJs)

Tags: javascript

I have a table like below. I can get sum of column with below javascript code block. But sometimes I can get sum of column and sometimes I can not get sum of column. All values of column are integer because the values consist of the sum of the rows. How can I fix it ?

For example:

| Column |
| --- |
| 5 |
| 10 |
| 22 |
| Sum : NaN |

| Column |
| --- |
| 5 |
| 10 |
| 22 |
| Sum : 37 |

The code block:

```
summaryRenderer: function(val, params, data, metaData) {

if(val !== null && val !==undefined && val !=="" && val !== NaN ){
  return '<span style=color:#00B2EE;font-weight:bold;text-align: center;>'+val+'</span>' ;
}
```

Comment: please add relevant html and javascript parts.

Comment: I can not share unfortunately. @NinaScholz

Comment: can you please put console.log(val) in summaryRenderer function to check value is correct or not

Comment: I tried it and it couldn't work I think it doesn't work on ExtJS. @ParthMDave

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    fullscreen:true,
    renderTo: document.body,
    features: [{
        ftype: 'summary'
    }],
    store: {
        data: [{
            num: 5
        },{
            num: 10
        },{
            num: 22
        }]
    },
    columns: [{
        dataIndex: 'num',
        width:"100%",
        text: 'Column',
        summaryType: 'sum',
        summaryRenderer: function(val, params, data, metaData) {
            if(val !== null && val !==undefined && val !=="" && val !== NaN ){
              return 'Sum :'+'<span style=color:#00B2EE;font-weight:bold;text-align: center;>'+val+'</span>' ;
            }}
    }]
});
```

**Add **"summaryType"**  config to the column.This configuration specifies the type of summary.Your code works fine,refer the attached code and the image.**

[image]

Comment: You could also simplify that if a little with typecheck/truthiness, e.g. `if (typeof val === 'number' && val)`